Federated Signin with Amplify using AWS Cognito
I am new to UI (react) and looking for some help to get the user authenticated with Oauth endpoints using AWS Amplify and AWS Cognito.
I tried InitAuth endpoints by AWS amplify and it is working, but it is not returning all scopes in JWT token. I didn't get any proper documentation of amplify through which I can use federated endpoints to configure AWS amplify to get the signing working with Cognito.
Any type of help is appreciated.
